# Scala how do i modify values in a Map[String, List[String, Set[String]]]

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I have a Map of type `Map[String, List[(String, Set[String]])]`
eg : `Map(ABC -> List((ABC, Set(X)))`

I need to update it to `Map[String, Set[String]]`

Output : `Map(ABC -> Set(X))`

Mainly need to remove the `List[String]` Part from values.

Comment: It’s not clear how you want to deal with the possibility of multiple elements of the list in each map entry. Do you want to only take the set from the first element, or combine all of the sets into a union set for each map entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can do `.mapValues`

```
val m: Map[String, List[(String, Set[String])]] = 
  Map("ABC" -> List(("ABC", Set("X"))))

// taking the set from the head of list, ignoring second "ABC"
val m1: Map[String, Set[String]] = m.view.mapValues(_.head._2).toMap
// Map(ABC -> Set(X))

// combining into union the sets from the whole list, ignoring second "ABC"
val m2: Map[String, Set[String]] =
  m.view.mapValues(_.map(_._2).fold(Set())(_ union _)).toMap
// Map(ABC -> Set(X))

// ignoring first "ABC"
val m3: Map[String, Set[String]] = m.values.flatten.toMap
// Map(ABC -> Set(X))
```

(`m3` is courtesy of **@Philluminati**)

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/maps.html

Comment: Also this works: `m.values.flatten.toMap`

Comment: @Philluminati Cool, thanks. It depends on what OP wants. If the strings `"ABC"`, `"ABC1"` are different in `val m = Map("ABC" -> List(("ABC1", Set("X"))))` then both `m.view.mapValues(_.head._2).toMap` and `m.view.mapValues(_.map(_._2).fold(Set())(_ union _)).toMap` produce `Map("ABC" -> Set("X"))` while `m.values.flatten.toMap` produces `Map("ABC1" -> Set("X"))`.

Comment: Yeah it’s hard to give a definitive answer because the problem isn’t clearly specified. I’m voting to close as “needs details or clarity”.

Comment: @TimMoore Since the OP accepted the answer, probably we guessed one of the options correctly :)